Spark and HDFS cluster running on docker
I'm trying to set up a Spark application running on my local machine to connect to an HDFS cluster where the NameNode is running inside a Docker container.
Here are the relevant details of my setup:
version: "3.9"

networks:
  hadoop-net:
    driver: bridge

services:
  # Distributed storage
  hdfs-namenode:
    container_name: "hdfs-namenode"
    image: "apache/hadoop:3"
    hostname: "hdfs-namenode"
    command: ["hdfs", "namenode"]
    ports:
      - "8020:8020"
      - "9870:9870"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop-config/config.env
    environment:
      ENSURE_NAMENODE_DIR: "/tmp/hadoop-root/dfs/name"
    networks:
      - hadoop-net

  hdfs-datanode:
    depends_on:
      hdfs-namenode:
        condition: service_started
    container_name: "hdfs-datanode"
    image: "apache/hadoop:3"
    hostname: "hdfs-datanode"
    command: ["hdfs", "datanode"]
    ports:
      - "9864:9864"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop-config/config.env
    networks:
      - hadoop-net

Here is the docker inspect network:
[
    {
        "Name": "big-data-project-2_hadoop-net",
        "Id": "9041e00edf94dfc3bbd06faa11e38158db0c008468a4d39439d6ffce86bcbaa9",
        "Created": "2024-12-02T16:27:49.568119343Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "5d35ac2b9390085f0a3318d2276f24be01738be5d61f12e33ecf57bfb843141c": {
                "Name": "hdfs-datanode",
                "EndpointID": "306e4bd76957da95b27828b938222b8ea9790ffefe53db6e2af7ab77cc0317d1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "90d2484e199081c06e40eebcfeca44e9fbb82eb77e24aaf5655564f3302b052a": {
                "Name": "hdfs-namenode",
                "EndpointID": "7ae97198be0b0fdf678784f4645f7fecbb31b7c559021ffbe8ac7153ebb272fc",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "hadoop-net",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "big-data-project-2",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.24.6"
        }
    }
]

So I'm trying to write a csv file to my HDFS cluster. I'm using this code as an exemple :
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:8020") \
    .appName("Spark SQL") \
    .getOrCreate()
    
data = [("James", "", "Smith",), ("Anna", "Rose", ""), ("Julia", "", "Williams")]
columns = ["firstname", "middlename", "lastname"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

df.show()

df.write.csv("/user/hadoop/data/people.csv")

The error is :
24/12/02 18:04:31 WARN DataStreamer: Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1073741841_1017
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/172.18.0.3:9866]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createSocketForPipeline(DataStreamer.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1728)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:713)
24/12/02 18:04:31 WARN DataStreamer: Abandoning BP-1037713087-172.18.0.2-1733156872096:blk_1073741841_1017
24/12/02 18:04:31 WARN DataStreamer: Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1073741842_1018
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/172.18.0.3:9866]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createSocketForPipeline(DataStreamer.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1728)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:713)
24/12/02 18:04:31 WARN DataStreamer: Abandoning BP-1037713087-172.18.0.2-1733156872096:blk_1073741842_1018
24/12/02 18:04:31 WARN DataStreamer: Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1073741843_1019
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/172.18.0.3:9866]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createSocketForPipeline(DataStreamer.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1728)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:713)
24/12/02 18:04:31 WARN DataStreamer: Abandoning BP-1037713087-172.18.0.2-1733156872096:blk_1073741843_1019
24/12/02 18:04:32 WARN DataStreamer: Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[172.18.0.3:9866,DS-deaa7ec2-a939-4f64-9f80-d8b5fa30f427,DISK]
24/12/02 18:04:32 WARN DataStreamer: Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[172.18.0.3:9866,DS-deaa7ec2-a939-4f64-9f80-d8b5fa30f427,DISK]
24/12/02 18:04:32 WARN DataStreamer: Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[172.18.0.3:9866,DS-deaa7ec2-a939-4f64-9f80-d8b5fa30f427,DISK]
24/12/02 18:04:32 WARN DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/hadoop/data/people.csv/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_202412021803316929840877291183176_0003_m_000015_31/part-00015-964739f3-b6f7-4f07-97a4-fbf380d50050-c000.csv could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:912)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1094)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1017)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1899)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:3048)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:129)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:530)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor203.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.addBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1088)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1915)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:713)......

The path is created but the file is empty
Overview

Where is the Spark code running?

Locally, outside the docker

You should change the code
from
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:8020") \

to
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://hdfs-namenode:8020") \

Because from your hadoop hdfs-datanode can't access hdfs://localhost:8020, it should be hdfs://hdfs-namenode:8020.

This assumes Spark code is running in a container on the docker network

He is right ! But here I wanna try to connect to HDFS with spark running locally

@Paul The namenode cannot advertise both itself and the datanode connections both as localhost... It'll break replication mechanics, even with 1 replica... So you must run Spark-Master, at the very least in a container. then 1) spark-submit to spark://localhost as the master 2) Use hdfs://hdfs-namenode:8020, as answered.
